# Joining one column from a file to another file based on matched value of first column in both

Tags: csv, sorting, unix, join, command-line

Using `join` command in linux, I would like to compare first column of `file1.csv` and `file2.csv` and where the column matches, I would like to add a column of `file2.csv` to `file1.csv`. The first column in `file1.csv` and `file2.csv` differs and `file1.csv` is a subset of `file2.csv` (first column wise).

```
head file1.csv 
column1, column2, column3
1.0, 5, 3
1.5, 4, 9
2.1, 2, 1
```

and

```
head file2.csv 
column1, column2, column4
1.0, 5, 9
1.2, 0, 0
1.3, 0, 1
1.5, 4, 3
2.1, 2, 5
```

I want to `join` such that afterwards:

```
head file1.csv 
column1, column2, column3, column4
1.0, 5, 3, 9
1.5, 4, 9, 3
2.1, 2, 1, 5
```

I tried `join -1 1 -2 1 -t, -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,2.3 <(sort -k 1 file1.csv ) <(sort -k 1 file2.csv )` but it's not working. Because it's also brings the header line bottom:

```
join -1 1 -2 1 -t, -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,2.3 <(sort -k 1 file1.csv ) <(sort -k 1 file2.csv )
1.0, 5, 3, 9
1.5, 4, 9, 3
2.1, 2, 1, 5
column1, column2, column3, column4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just concerned about the head columns placed position?

Try it following one. It just modified your command line a little.

```
join -1 1 -2 1 -t, -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,2.3 <(head -n 1 file1.csv && tail -n+2 file1.csv | sort -k1 ) <(head -n 1 file2.csv && tail -n+2 file2.csv | sort -k1 )
```

I hope this helps you.